# C++ error: invalid suffix '.d' on floating constant

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello I have the following declared arrays in C++:

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,0};
float arr2[10] = {1.2f,0.0f,2.0f,1.4f,0.0f,4.2f,5.3f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
double arr3[6] = {0.0d,0.0d,5.3d,0.0d,0.0d,0.5d};
```

When I compile this code the compiler returns the following error:

> error: invalid suffix '.d' on floating constant

I tried compiling using the flag *-std=c++11* to try and see if it worked on C++ 11 but I get the same error. Can someone tell me where the error is? Thank you :)

Comment: `d` is not a valid suffix on a floating point literal. Just drop it.

Comment: It seems `d` prefix is a GCC extension. Use GCC if you want to use that.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the suffix and it worked.

Comment: If `d` is supposed to be for double, then just don't use it. Its not needed.

Comment: If I were to run it using the GCC extension how would I do that on OSx?

Comment: @redGarrian _"If I were to run it using the GCC extension how would I do that on OSx?"_ Do yyou have a GCC toolchain installed there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Floating point literal suffixes are](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal):

```
(no suffix) defines double
f F defines float
l L defines long double
```

Supposed you put the `d` to make the literal a `double`, you can remove it. I suppose gcc offers it as extension for the sake of consistency (allows to use a suffix also for `double`s), but also gcc will accept no suffix and the type of the literal will be `double`.

Comment: It's also needed when no-suffix means float with -fsingle-precision-constant